# How to make a clickable and animated textview?

Tags: android, viewpropertyanimator

I need to implement a moving/scrolling textview that got a clickable span. I also need to make the animation look like those banner ads below the news that repeat and repeat endlessly. I used TranslateAnimation before for a tv app and able to have it work because what I get is the keyEvent and the the touch. I need to implement it now on a tablet app which doesn't have any external input source other than the touchscreen itself.

I tried to use TranslateAnimation again for the tablet app but it doesn't work. Upon searching about the different animation I could use, I've learned that TranslateAnimation just animates the look of the view and the the whole view itself. It doesn't move the clickable parts with the look so I looked for a different one.

Then I stumbled upon PropertyAnimator. It's what I clearly need for my problem. But there's also a drawback to it. It doesn't support repeating.

What I currently have is this code below.

```
        lbl.animate();
        lbl.animate().x(-lblWidth).y(0);
        lbl.animate().setDuration(animDuration);
        lbl.animate().setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        lbl.animate().setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                lbl.animate();
                lbl.animate().x(lblWidth).y(0);
                lbl.animate().setDuration(0);
                lbl.animate().x(-lblWidth).y(0);
                lbl.animate().setDuration(animDuration);
                lbl.animate().setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                lbl.animate().setListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });
```

After the first run, the animation ends. It repeats because it prints my log but it's not showing on screen.

I was trying to make a repeating effect with that code. I was trying to recreate something like this code below.

```
            transAnim = new TranslateAnimation(
                    TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f,
                    TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,
                    TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
                    TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f
            );

            transAnim.setRepeatCount(-1);
            transAnim.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
            transAnim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            transAnim.setDuration(animDuration);
            transAnim.setFillAfter(true);
```

What the code above does is from the right, outside the screen, I start an animation that goes to the left, outside the screen. Then, if the view's end reach the left, outside the screen, tell the animation to restart from the beginning.

I made it work now by adding a single short line of code above everything.

```
    lbl.setX(screenWidth);
    lbl.animate().x(-lblWidth).y(0);
    lbl.animate().setDuration(animDuration);
    lbl.animate().setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```

Then using those line of code again on the onAnimationEnd of the animate listener. Now I thought of another thing, can I pause this animation? Because I found a way to do it for TranslateAnimation. Is there a hack way to do it?

Comment: On your `onAnimationEnd` you are using two `setDuration`. Is this necessary?

Comment: Try This [Link](https://www.viralandroid.com/2015/12/create-scrolling-text-marquee-in-android-textview.html)

Comment: @Tepits tbh, I don't really know how to use it. I just learned about it today.

Comment: @Sniffer I used before but I don't if it supports pausing that's why I didn't use it on my current case

Answer (score 0):

Try this I hope it work for you.

```
 lbl.animate();
 lbl.animate().x(-lblWidth).y(0);
 lbl.animate().setDuration(animDuration);
 lbl.animate().setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
 lbl.animate().setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```

Comment: there's no setRepeatCount on animate()

Comment: Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 500,0, 0);
    animation.setDuration(1000);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    view.startAnimation(animation);

Try this.

Comment: So, it's also using TranslateAnimation. Do you have a solution using ViewPropertyAnimation?